# ajax if result = 1 show message in div

Tags: php, ajax

I want when the result is 1 DIV showed

my php code

```
   if($FileType != "zip" && $FileType != "ZIP") {
       echo '1';
    }
```

my html form code

```
<form id="my-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <textarea id="_text" name="text" required=""></textarea>
 <input id="_from" name="from" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
 <input name="to" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $touser; ?>"/>
 <input name="post" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $postid ?>"  />

 <div class="file">
 <li>ملفات .zip فقط</li>
 <input class="up" type="file" name="up" />
 </div>


 <button class="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

my javascript code

```
<script>
$( '#my-form' )
.submit( function( e ) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'chat_a.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData( this ),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
} );
e.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("my-form").reset();
});
</script>
```

I want when the result is 1 DIV showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `success` or `done` function (depending on the version of jQuery). For the latest versions you would use [`done`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'chat_a.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData( this ),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    if(msg == '1') {
         // your code here
     }
});
```

From the docs -

> Deprecation Notice: The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add a success handler:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'chat_a.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData( this ),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success:function(response){
        if(response == "1")
        {
         // DO YOUR STUFF
        }
    }
} );
```

**UPDATE:**
add the comma after `contentType: false`.

I have already done that in the answer.

Comment: <script>
 $( '#my-form' )
 .submit( function( e ) {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'chat_a.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: new FormData( this ),
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success:function(response){
  if(response == "1")
  {
   $('#error').show();
  }
 }
 } );
 e.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById("my-form").reset();
 });
 </script>

<div id="error" style="display: none;">nooooo</div>   The code does not work

Comment: `contentType: false` need to be `contentType: false,`